# printJS having issue while printing base64 to pdf in safari browser

Tags: pdf, safari, base64, printjs

Unable to print in Safari browser using **printjs** to print base64 to pdf.

It works well in Chrome but on Safari it opens the print window but with no data.

[Here is the sample image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djjye.png)

Here is the sample code

```
 printJS({
          printable: samplebase64response,
          type: 'pdf',
          base64: true,
  })
```

tried other solution too but nothing worked. The print window comes blank.

The data should be loaded for the printing in the print window.